# error while creating procedure in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, procedure, amazon-athena

i am trying to create a procedure to query a AWS Athena datalake and get the below error.

SQL Error [100071] [HY000]: [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. line 1:1: mismatched input 'Begin'

please guide
the query is below.

```
declare basemonth as date;
set basemonth = date(2021-08-01)
While Date_add(month,1,basemonth) < date(2022-07-31);
Begin
select country , plan_validity, count(distinct A.userid) from db.tbl A
where A.plan_validity = '30' and lower(A.country) = 'united kingdom' and A.startdate between Date ('2021-08-01') and Date('2021-10-31') 
and A.userid in
(select distinct userid from db.tbl 
where plan_validity = '30' and lower(country) = 'united kingdom' and startdate between basemonth and Date('2021-08-31'))
group by 1,2
end;
```

Comment: What makes you think such a query would be supported by athena at all?

Comment: okay...so whats the alternative to run queries in loops in Athena

Comment: Amazon Athena supports reasonably-standard SQL syntax for the SELECT statement, but does not support stored procedures. It is a query engine, not a database. Can you tell us more about your actual requirement?

Comment: i have to check for distinct users who are new in a particular month and then track their status (active/inactive) for the subsequent months.

Comment: The above is a minute scenario where i get the unique Id's in the inner query and the outer query was checking the status for each month after it